# unwanted automatic change wallpaper

Tags: desktop-background, guest-session

I've got a problem. My fellow worker changed my wallpaper on the guest account (stupid joke). Now I've got a completely mess. The Wallpaper changes automatically every couple of seconds. And when I try to delete the file with the stupid wallpaper in it, it is automatically restored to  my home directory. Please help.

Comment: All changes made to the computer including system settings changes and file changes are meant to be deleted after exiting the guest account. This sounds very much like a bug what you are experiencing.

Comment: Is this because your friend has changed the wallpaper from what had previously been set to one which changes automatically? You can reset it by selecting Settings > Appearance > and selecting a different Wallpaper.

Comment: I tried to change settings and it's ok for about 2 minutes. After this time wallpaper is automatically changing to default ubuntu wallpaper and then it sometimes change to the wallpaper which my friend created and his file over and over again appears in my home directory.

Comment: As "Toroidal" correctly stated: All your changes in the settings will be deleted and not restored after reboot if you used a guest account. You have to ask the system administrator to change the setting, since he/she has root privileges!

Answer (score 0):

This article will help you to change the guest account's settings: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizeGuestSession

As you know, at every login you get a completely fresh guest session which will be fully deleted after logout too. But interesting is what happens at the login: To create a new temporary guest session (home directory is in /tmp/guest-XXXXX), Ubuntu takes the contents from /etc/skel/ (default stuff for all users) and /etc/guest-session/skel/ (default guest) and creates the temporary account of it. So to change the guest settings, you will have to change the contents of /etc/guest-session/skel. This is usually done by either replacing this directory with a symbolic link to another user's home path (a hidden user only for tweaking the guest account preferably) or by logging into a guest session and copying its active home directory contents with root permissions to the /etc/guest-session/skel/ folder (from a superuser account logged in parallel).

Any more problems, or did you understand everything? I suppose you to read the article to understand better what you do. It is described in more detail there.
Greetings and good luck!

Comment: Nothing changed. Wallpaper changes randomly between default and my friend.

Comment: Sorry, then I can't imagine what happened to your machine. What about asking your "friend" what exactly he did? It could cost you a bottle of wine maybe (depends on what a good friend he is...), but I personally don't see any other options by now... Sorry :(

Comment: He said he only changed wallpaper on guest account, nothing more. His file is named rdc.jpg and appears in my home directory. When i delete it it come back in couple of seconds and wallpaper changes randomly each him and default ubuntu wallpaper. Maybe there is a chance to block changing wallpaper from root account?

Comment: Would be interesting HOW he did this (exact steps). Did he create another account as guest session default, or did he copy the modified session to the defaults folder using an admin account? Or...?